# How to restrict Spark Driver Pods to spin off only Spark Executors, and not random pods?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, rbac

The Spark Driver's Service Account must be tied to a Role that has "Create Pod" access to spin off Spark Executors.

This leads to Security Issue, where a bad actor can write a "Spark" Job to spin off another set of Random Pods.
Example: The Spark Job Python file could have the below command to create another Pod that can perform destructive operations.

```
KUBE_TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $KUBE_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT/api/v1/namespaces/mysparknamespace/pods/ -d@podspecwithbadthings.json
```

How can restrict the Role Permissions of Spark Driver to spin off only its Spark Executors and not random pods ?

Comment: What have you already tried and what bad outcome is it producing for you?

Comment: I spun off an SparkJob-1 whose ServiceAccount-1 is tied to IAMRole-1. As part of SparkJob-1, I programmatically created another Driver Pod whose ServiceAccount-2 is tied to IAMRole-2.  With this Setup, a User who has access to run jobs with IAMRole-1 can also spun off another Spark Job with IAMRole-2 as well.